Docker won't accept the path
This my code
get_model.py
import torch
from PIL import Image
import io
from pathlib import Path
import os

model_path = Path(os.path.abspath("./models/best.pt"))
yolo_model = Path("./yolov5")

def get_yolov5():
    # local
    # model = torch.hub.load(yolo_model, "custom", path=model_path, source="local", force_reload=True)

    # online
    model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "custom", path=model_path, force_reload=True)

    # direct
    # model = torch.load(str(model_path))
    # model.eval()

    # model.conf = 0.5
    return model


def get_image_from_bytes(binary_image, max_size=1024):
    input_image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(binary_image)).convert("RGB")
    width, height = input_image.size
    resize_factor = min(max_size / width, max_size / height)
    resized_image = input_image.resize(
        (
            int(input_image.width * resize_factor),
            int(input_image.height * resize_factor),
        )
    )
    return resized_image


main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File
from get_model import get_yolov5, get_image_from_bytes
from starlette.responses import Response
import io
from PIL import Image
import json
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


model = get_yolov5()

app = FastAPI(
    title="Custom YOLOV5 Machine Learning API",
    description="""Obtain object value out of image
                    and return image and json result""",
    version="0.0.1",
)

origins = [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "*"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# @app.get('/')
# def read_root():
#     return {'message': 'Recipe Recommendation API go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs#/'}

@app.get('/notify/v1/health')
def get_health():
    return dict(msg='OK')


@app.post("/object-to-json")
async def detect_food_return_json_result(file: bytes = File(...)):
    input_image = get_image_from_bytes(file)
    results = model(input_image)
    detect_res = results.pandas().xyxy[0].to_json(orient="records")
    detect_res = json.loads(detect_res)
    return {"result": detect_res}


@app.post("/object-to-img")
async def detect_food_return_base64_img(file: bytes = File(...)):
    input_image = get_image_from_bytes(file)
    results = model(input_image)
    results.render()

    # https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/9621
    for img in results.ims:
        bytes_io = io.BytesIO()
        img_base64 = Image.fromarray(img)
        img_base64.save(bytes_io, format="jpeg")
    return Response(content=bytes_io.getvalue(), media_type="image/jpeg")


and this is my docker logs when i try to run it
2024-06-19 02:11:11 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/hub.py:293: UserWarning: You are about to download and run code from an untrusted repository. In a future release, this won't be allowed. To add the repository to your trusted list, change the command to {calling_fn}(..., trust_repo=False) and a command prompt will appear asking for an explicit confirmation of trust, or load(..., trust_repo=True), which will assume that the prompt is to be answered with 'yes'. You can also use load(..., trust_repo='check') which will only prompt for confirmation if the repo is not already trusted. This will eventually be the default behaviour
2024-06-19 02:11:11   warnings.warn(
2024-06-19 02:11:11 Downloading: "https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/zipball/master" to /root/.cache/torch/hub/master.zip
2024-06-19 02:11:16 Collecting ultralytics
2024-06-19 02:11:17   Downloading ultralytics-8.2.35-py3-none-any.whl (782 kB)
2024-06-19 02:11:17      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 782.8/782.8 kB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2024-06-19 02:11:17 Requirement already satisfied: tqdm>=4.64.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (4.66.4)
2024-06-19 02:11:18 Collecting psutil
2024-06-19 02:11:18   Downloading psutil-5.9.8-cp36-abi3-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (288 kB)
2024-06-19 02:11:18      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 288.2/288.2 kB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2024-06-19 02:11:19 Collecting opencv-python>=4.6.0
2024-06-19 02:11:19   Downloading opencv_python-4.10.0.84-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (62.5 MB)
2024-06-19 02:12:08      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.5/62.5 MB 1.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2024-06-19 02:12:08 Collecting scipy>=1.4.1
2024-06-19 02:12:08   Downloading scipy-1.13.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (38.6 MB)
2024-06-19 02:12:39      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 38.6/38.6 MB 1.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=7.1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (10.3.0)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: torchvision>=0.9.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (0.18.1+cpu)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml>=5.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (6.0.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (1.26.4)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Collecting py-cpuinfo
2024-06-19 02:12:39   Downloading py_cpuinfo-9.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (2.3.1+cpu)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Collecting ultralytics-thop>=2.0.0
2024-06-19 02:12:39   Downloading ultralytics_thop-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib>=3.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (3.9.0)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.23.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (2.32.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=1.1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (2.2.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: seaborn>=0.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultralytics) (0.13.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (3.1.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.3.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (1.4.5)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (2.9.0.post0)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: contourpy>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (1.2.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: packaging>=20.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (24.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: fonttools>=4.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (4.53.0)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (0.12.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:39 Requirement already satisfied: importlib-resources>=3.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (6.4.0)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas>=1.1.4->ultralytics) (2024.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: tzdata>=2022.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas>=1.1.4->ultralytics) (2024.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->ultralytics) (2.2.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->ultralytics) (2024.6.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->ultralytics) (3.3.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.23.0->ultralytics) (3.7)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=4.8.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (4.12.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: filelock in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (3.15.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: networkx in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (3.2.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (3.1.4)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: sympy in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (1.12.1)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: fsspec in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (2024.6.0)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=3.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from importlib-resources>=3.2.0->matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (3.19.2)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib>=3.3.0->ultralytics) (1.16.0)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jinja2->torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (2.1.5)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Requirement already satisfied: mpmath<1.4.0,>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from sympy->torch>=1.8.0->ultralytics) (1.3.0)
2024-06-19 02:12:40 Installing collected packages: py-cpuinfo, scipy, psutil, opencv-python, ultralytics-thop, ultralytics
2024-06-19 02:12:47 Successfully installed opencv-python-4.10.0.84 psutil-5.9.8 py-cpuinfo-9.0.0 scipy-1.13.1 ultralytics-8.2.35 ultralytics-thop-2.0.0
2024-06-19 02:12:47 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
2024-06-19 02:12:47 
2024-06-19 02:12:47 [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.0.1 -> 24.0
2024-06-19 02:12:47 [notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
2024-06-19 02:12:51 YOLOv5  2024-6-18 Python-3.9.19 torch-2.3.1+cpu CPU
2024-06-19 02:12:51 
2024-06-19 02:12:51 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 50, in _create
2024-06-19 02:12:51     model = DetectMultiBackend(path, device=device, fuse=autoshape)  # detection model
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/common.py", line 467, in __init__
2024-06-19 02:12:51     model = attempt_load(weights if isinstance(weights, list) else w, device=device, inplace=True, fuse=fuse)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/experimental.py", line 98, in attempt_load
2024-06-19 02:12:51     ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location="cpu")  # load
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1025, in load
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return _load(opened_zipfile,
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1446, in _load
2024-06-19 02:12:51     result = unpickler.load()
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1084, in __new__
2024-06-19 02:12:51     raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
2024-06-19 02:12:51 NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system
2024-06-19 02:12:51 
2024-06-19 02:12:51 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2024-06-19 02:12:51 
2024-06-19 02:12:51 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 65, in _create
2024-06-19 02:12:51     model = attempt_load(path, device=device, fuse=False)  # arbitrary model
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/models/experimental.py", line 98, in attempt_load
2024-06-19 02:12:51     ckpt = torch.load(attempt_download(w), map_location="cpu")  # load
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1025, in load
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return _load(opened_zipfile,
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 1446, in _load
2024-06-19 02:12:51     result = unpickler.load()
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1084, in __new__
2024-06-19 02:12:51     raise NotImplementedError("cannot instantiate %r on your system"
2024-06-19 02:12:51 NotImplementedError: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system
2024-06-19 02:12:51 
2024-06-19 02:12:51 The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2024-06-19 02:12:51 
2024-06-19 02:12:51 Traceback (most recent call last):
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/bin/uvicorn", line 8, in <module>
2024-06-19 02:12:51     sys.exit(main())
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
2024-06-19 02:12:51     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 410, in main
2024-06-19 02:12:51     run(
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 577, in run
2024-06-19 02:12:51     server.run()
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 65, in run
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return loop.run_until_complete(main)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1517, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 69, in serve
2024-06-19 02:12:51     await self._serve(sockets)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 76, in _serve
2024-06-19 02:12:51     config.load()
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py", line 434, in load
2024-06-19 02:12:51     self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/importer.py", line 19, in import_from_string
2024-06-19 02:12:51     module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/resepee-yoloV5-FastAPI/main.py", line 10, in <module>
2024-06-19 02:12:51     model = get_yolov5()
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/resepee-yoloV5-FastAPI/get_model.py", line 14, in get_yolov5
2024-06-19 02:12:51     model = torch.hub.load("ultralytics/yolov5", "custom", path=model_path, force_reload=True)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 568, in load
2024-06-19 02:12:51     model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/hub.py", line 597, in _load_local
2024-06-19 02:12:51     model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 88, in custom
2024-06-19 02:12:51     return _create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=_verbose, device=device)
2024-06-19 02:12:51   File "/root/.cache/torch/hub/ultralytics_yolov5_master/hubconf.py", line 83, in _create
2024-06-19 02:12:51     raise Exception(s) from e
2024-06-19 02:12:51 Exception: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True` or see https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/pytorch_hub_model_loading for help.


2024-06-19 02:12:51 Exception: cannot instantiate 'WindowsPath' on your system. Cache may be out of date, try `force_reload=True` or see https://docs.ultralytics.com/yolov5/tutorials/pytorch_hub_model_loading for help.

i try all approach to path to specific folder but none of them was succesfull. is there any suggestion ?
the approach i try is

using pathlib
using os
using double and single backslash (\ and \)
using double and single forwardslash (/ and //)

and there is no answer on the internet or am i mising it

Have you checked the URL in the error message?
